# How to add close button on dynamically created tab pages in windows form C#

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol

How to add close button on dynamically created tab pages in windows form C#
?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is one way to do it:

First, when creating the page, also create the button:

```
var page = new TabPage("dynamic");
var btn = new Button();
btn.Text = "close";
btn.Click += btn_Click;
page.Controls.Add(btn);
this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(page);
```

Then, in the btn_Click event handler, write something like this:

```
var page = (TabPage)((Button)sender).Parent;
this.tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(page);
```